# problem hooking NT dll file functions!

Tags: file-io, kernel, hook

what is the best tool to track the NT API's.

Comment: Perhaps try stepping through the setup in olly and following it until it reaches the function you need to hook. This will probably be very tedious (especially if it's packed or crypted) though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in the desired process then you can redirect the IAT ( import address table) for the dll that you want to monitor.
If you are not already running code in process then you will also need to find a way to load your code into the desired process.

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft's Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) can help you do this, and it's free.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is on the beam, but try this for Win32. For Native API, I think only about 20% of it is documented.

- [Win32 API Monitor](http://www.woodmann.com/collaborative/tools/index.php/Win32_API_Monitor)